# VS 2010 running Opencv240 application on x64 machine: tbb.dll is missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am running an opencv240 application with Visual Studio 2010 on Win7 x64 machine. The app. builds ok but when running, I get the following error:

tbb.dll is missing...

Although tbb.dll is available under C:\OpenCV-2.4.0\opencv\build\common\tbb\intel64\vc10.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

tbb or tbb_debug under running it in debug mode? In any case you should include it in your path. In the case of tbb_debug, it isn't included in the opencv archive thus download it manually from http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/.

Answer (score 0):

add the path of the missing dll to the environment variables present under

win7 - mycomputer:properties->advanced system settings (to the left) -> environment variables (bottom right) -> new .... the path goes in the value column